# OnClick location Not Work

Tags: onclick, printf

**this Line not work properly /r work but $siteurl/%s-%s.html not work i think problem of ("") or ('') please help me to repair it

```
printf("<a href='/r?%s' target=_blank onClick='window.open(location.href=$siteurl/%s-%s.html)>", $wurl, $myrow["wallpaperid"], $myrow["wallpapername"]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use double-quotes within double-quotes (unless you escape them properly):

```
<a onclick="location.href='http://google.com'">Click Me</a>
```

Note how I use single-quotes within my double-quotes. This keeps the statement from being abandoned prematurely.

You could have also written it like this:

```
<a onclick="location.href=\"http://google.com\"">Click Me</a>
```

But that makes it slightly less readable.

Answer (score 1):

Your onClick attribute misses the trailing single quote. Here's what I think it should be:

```
printf("<a href='/r?%s' target=_blank onClick='window.open(location.href=$siteurl/%s-%s.html)'>", $wurl, $myrow["wallpaperid"], $myrow["wallpapername"]);
```

BTW: I had a hard time reading even this single line. Consider indenting your code to make it human-readable. Also, I recommend against using variable substitution (the $siteurl var in your string) when you are using printf anyway. I mean, use the same mechanism to do the same thing. Either use only var substitution, or use only printf formattng, not both. Example:

```
$html = '
    <a  href="/r?%s" 
        target=_blank 
        onClick="window.open(location.href=%s/%s-%s.html)"
    >
';
printf($html, $wurl, $siteurl, $myrow["wallpaperid"], $myrow["wallpapername"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a single quote mark after .html)

Try:

```
printf("<a href='/r?%s' target=_blank onClick='window.open(location.href=$siteurl/%s-%s.html)'>", $wurl, $myrow["wallpaperid"], $myrow["wallpapername"]);
```